# New to bootstrap: does bootstrap not use <frame> tag to do web development?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am new to bootstrap and haven't done a lot of web development for many years.  I'm trying to use bootstrap to do a sliding menu bar on the left of the web page and want to know what the best way to code it is.  Back then we used  tags to show different content using the same menu bar as a "static" separate frame.  Is there a more efficient way of implementing frame type of design on my website using bootstrap?  sorry if my questions are a little vague.

Basically I want to use a static menu bar that shows different "cool" content on a main page view without having to rewrite the same code for each new main page.

thanks in advance

bootstrap 4

Comment: It sounds like what you're trying to achieve relates more to using a component-based approach, which was indeed achieved using frames before. Things have changed _a lot_ since in web dev so I suggest you just take it from scratch honestly. Maybe look for things like webpack or parcel?

Comment: Is there a good tutorial for webpack?

Comment: Probably many, although I don't really know any.